# Disable navigation while Angular Foundation Modal is open

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

How do I disable the navigation along the pages in background when the angular foundation modal is open on top of it. Right now when the modal is opened, I can go backward and forward through the pages while the modal is still open.

Comment: How about posting some code examples to go along with your question?  Or a plunker/fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and resolve it this way:

**The Focus problem**:

When modal opens: In the options that you can set on `$modal()`, you can add an option `open` that is a function. In that function you can set the focus over some element of the modal or the modal itself:

```
$modal.open({
  //...
  opened : function() {
    $timeout(function() {
      $('#firstModalButton').focus();
    }, 300);
  }
});
```

I had to add the timeout, because the opened callback according to foundation page:

> promise that is resolved when a modal gets opened after downloading content's template and resolving all variables

But I couldn't add a focus without the timeout, the promise is resolved before the HTML were appended to the DOM.

**The Navigation problem**:

You should check when your application state changes:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function() {
  var modal = $modalStack.getTop();
  modal.key.dismiss();
});
```